# Amazon EMR w/ Hadoop 3.1

Tags: apache-spark, amazon-emr

I'm writing a large dataset in Parquet format to HDFS using Spark and it runs rather slowly in EMR vs say Databricks. I realize that if I was able to use Hadoop 3.1, it would be much more performant because it has a high performance output committer. Is this the case, and if so - when will there be a version of EMR that uses Hadoop 3.1 ? The current version I'm using is 5.21.